# jquery touchswipe swipe function not working when not using $(document).on

Tags: javascript, jquery, touchswipe

I'm using jquery touchswipe but as I'm creating the dom element by javascript not by html itself, it doesn't work if I don't use `$(document).on('click', '.swipe-area')` instead of `$('.swipe-area').on('click')`. So my code:

```
$('.swipe-area').on('click', function() {
    alert('This Doesnt Work!');
});

$(document).on('click', '.swipe-area', function() {
    alert('This Works!');
});
```

However when I want to use `$('.swipe-area').swipe({//Some Functions Here...})` I don't know how I can select the `.swipe-area` with the second method above.

**UPDATE**

Here is my complete code:

```
<script>
$('.swipe-area').swipe({
    swipeStatus: function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers)
    {
        if (phase=='move' && direction =='left') {
            $('#sidebar').addClass('open-sidebar');
            $('.swipe-area').css('background-color', 'transparent');
            $('.sidemenu-overlay').show();
            return false;
        }
        if (phase=='move' && direction =='right') {
            $('#sidebar').removeClass('open-sidebar');
            $('.swipe-area').css('background-color', 'rgba(22, 184, 186, 0.5)');
            $('.sidemenu-overlay').hide();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
</script>

<div class="sidemenu-overlay"></div>
<div class="sidemenu">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="swipe-area"></div>
</div>

<style>
.sidemenu-overlay {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1031;
}

.sidemenu {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  top: -68px;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
  z-index: 1031;
}

.swipe-area {
  position: fixed;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(22, 184, 186, 0.5);
  z-index: 0;
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: #16b8ba;
  position: fixed;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100vh;
  right: -240px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 3px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: -2px 3px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#sidebar.open-sidebar {
  right: 0;
}

#sidebar ul li:hover {
  background-color: #187a8a;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
</style>
```

BTW surprisingly this code below works:

```
$('.p-paragraph-top-of-the-page').swipe({
    swipeStatus: function(event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers)
    {
        console.log(direction);
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to use JQuery .click method?

Comment: I don't want to do something on click event but on swipe.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
$(document).on('swipe', '.swipe-area', function() {
    alert('This Works!');
});
```

I guess your problem is caused because of `return false`. The only action needed to cancel the default behavior is preventDefault(). Issuing return false; can create brittle code. Usually, you'd want just this:

```
$("a").on( 'click', function (e) {
    // e == our event data
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: it seems it might be the correct answer but it didn't work either. I checked `z-index` in css and set it to 9999 too but no result :(

Comment: because I'm using vuejs and different components are separated I couldn't. But at first it was working but after some time it didn't cause of css I think!